# Ускорить выполнение PHP скрипта с объемными вычислениями

Tags: php, linux, сервер, debian

Есть PHP скрипт, выполняется на VPS (через CLI). В нем производятся очень объемные вычисления, скрипт может работать до нескольких суток. Код уже оптимизирован, может можно сделать что-нибудь с самим сервером для ускорения вычислений? В серверах ничего не понимаю.

PHP Version => 5.4.4-14+deb7u14

Comment: Перепишите код на C/C++, работать будет раз в дцать быстрее. А если еще многопоточность (при возможности) подключить...

Comment: Переходите на PHP 7, он быстрее должен быть.

Comment: Пишу только на php.

Comment: @yevgeniyche неудачный выбор для высоконагруженных вычислений.

Comment: что же вы там делаете такое, что несколько суток считает. но да, делать расчеты на пхп несколько странно.

Comment: php7 + ptreads. По железу - смотрите узкие места(CPU, RAM, IO) и анализируйте.